# regarding reshaping a multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a multidimensional array with shape `(15000,1,96,96),` where each 96*96 matrix represents an image. I would like to transform its shape to `(15000,96,96,1).`

Can I just use `a=a.reshape(15000,96,96,1)` to do it? Is that the right way?

Comment: You can use `reshape`, but if it is the right way depends on what you want the result to be. More likely you will want to use [`transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html), where you can rearrange the dimensions of the array: `a.transpose(0, 2, 3, 1)`

Comment: Can you demonstrate the `right` result using a smaller array reshape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific example you need to transpose the 2nd dimension with the final one. You can shuffle dimensions in a numpy array using the [transpose method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html):

For example:

```
a = np.zeros((10,1,96,96))
print(a.shape)
>>> (10, 1, 96, 96)

a = a.transpose(0,2,3,1)
print(a.shape)
>>> (10, 96, 96, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, generally what are the pro and cons for using reshape vs transpose in terms of solving this kind of problem.

Comment: Their are two very different functions actually. 
As an example with a 3D array : 
    a = np.arange(12).reshape((2,2,3))
    a.reshape((3,2,2))
    a.transpose((2,0,1))

Comment: You can think of reshaping as first raveling the array (using the given index order), then inserting the elements from the raveled array into the new array using the same kind of index ordering as was used for the raveling. While transpose does not unravel the array; it does the transposition of tensors.  So they do different task;

Because of raveling and unraveling; the reshape would change the order of elements in the arrays;

Answer (score 1):

To complete the comment of @OddNorg, here is an example:

Let's say you have 3 images of size (2*2):

```
>>>img0 = [[0,0],[0,0]]
>>>img1 = [[1,1],[1,1]]
>>>img2 = [[2,2],[2,2]]
>>>imgs = np.concatenate([[img0],[img1],[img2]])
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 0]],  

       [[1, 1],
        [1, 1]], 

       [[2, 2],
        [2, 2]]])
>>>imgs.shape
(3,2,2)
```

Now we want to have the pixels on the first and second dimensions instead of the second and the third.

if we use reshape it does work as expected :

```
>>>imgs_r = imgs.reshape((2,2,3))
>>>imgs_r[:,:,0]
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 2]])
```

The first image is modified

with transpose it's working fine and images are not modified :

```
>>>imgs_t = imgs.tranpose((1,2,0))
>>>imgs_t[:,:,0]
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0]])
```